# Update UILabel text from another class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a method implemented in the ViewCotroller class to set the message to a UILable in that class.

```
 -(void)setAuthenticationMessage:(NSString *)message{
        //lblStatus is the UILabel
        lblStatus.text = message;
 }
```

I'm accessing this method from another class to set the message. Though code executes correctly this message didn't update. I tried it by executing this method in a different thread. But that was also unsuccessful. Can anyone help me to figure out the issue?

Comment: How are you accessing the method from the other class? Are you creating a new instance of the class and then calling the method?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the function. Check that the var lblStatus is not nil. Also, are you doing this in a background thread? (If you are not sure about the thread then don't worry, you are OK with this).

Comment: Are you creating a new instance to call this method ? If yes. Then It won't work.

Comment: do you want pass message from parent class to child class.

Comment: First make sure that you have correct lblStatus reference. Dump the label's frame using NSStringFromCGRect and try to change some other properties (for example backgroundColor) to check if the reference you have points to the expected label in the view. Also once I had funny problem when you have synthesized ivar and private ivars with the same name, so check you @synthesize too.

Comment: you give more code about ur class,then only we get details about ur problem,you not specify the class detail simply give which method u call

Answer (score 0):

What are `lblStatus`'s memory management properties? Your naming convention alone leads me to believe that it is something to do with this. Usually you refer to instance variables as: 
`_lblStatus` or `self.lblStatus`

Answer (score 0):

use @protocol & delegates to access another class refer this link [example](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)   [example2](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/simple-objective-c-protocol-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate design pattern (google it). Example:

```
    //In the updating class .h

        @protocol LabelChangerDelegate <NSObject>
        -(void)handleLabelChangeMessage;
        @end

        @property (assign, nonatomic) id <LabelChangerDelegate> delegate;

       //In the updating class .m

        -(void)changeLabelInOtherClass{
         if (self.delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleLabelChangeMessage)]) {
                [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(handleLabelChangeMessage)];
            }
        } else {
         NSLog(@"Delgate doesn't implement handleLabelChangeMessage");
        }

        //In the view controller .h

        <LabelChangerDelegate>

        -(void)viewDidLoad{
         //set the delegate to self
        }

 //In the view controller .m

        -(void)handleLabelChangeMessage{
         self.label.text=@"I changed through delegation";
        }
```

Another option is to use NSNotificationCenter